# My bootstrap-based page isn't being responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

My page doesn't change to the xs-sized options when I resize my browser window to its minumnum width. What am I missing here?

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNEbGN)

HTML:

```
<head>
    <title>Sample Page Layout</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container nav">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3 about">About</div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3 events">Events</div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3 shop">Shop</div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3 contact">Contact</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.nav { width:100%; height:100px; background-color:#84d36f; }
.nav div { height:50%; line-height:50px; }
.col-xs-3 { font-size:0; background-color:red;}
.col-md-3 { font-size:1em; background-color:blue; }
.col-xs-3 .about { background-image:url(images/about.png); }
.col-xs-3 .events { background-image:url(images/events.png); }
.col-xs-3 .shop { background-image:url(images/shop.png); }
.col-xs-3 .contact { background-image:url(images/contact.png); }
```

Comment: First, I personally never modify grid elements like you've done. You're just asking for trouble. Instead, modify what's inside the grid. Then, were `.nav` and `.container` intended to be used simultaneously?

Comment: keep the `.container` on an outer `div` - add another `div` for the `.nav`, place it inside the `.container` - btw, if you want the same size for `.xs` and `.md` you can just simply specify the `.xs` and it will apply to all bigger sizes as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood what media queries do. They don't activate and deactivate classes. They control styles. Styles applied to any class are implemented based on standard CSS inheritance and specificity.

Instead of applying your styles to various grid classes, try this:

```
.col-xs-3 {font-size:0; background-color: blue;}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .col-xs-3 {font-size: 0; background-color: red;}
}
```

In this example, elements with class `.col-xs-3` (that aren't superceded by other, more specific style statements) will have a blue background unless the screen width is under 768px.